# Is there a way to define a custom order by strategy when using the javax.persistence.OrderBy annotation?

Tags: java, persistence, sql-order-by

From the docs I know we can specify a column, but is there a way to pass in a custom comparator and sort according to that?

So it might look something like this:

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@OrderBy("createdDateTime", comparator=StripYearComparator.class)
public List<A> getAs() {
    return result;
}
```

Anyone had the same use case as me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not that I know of @Tommy.  The whole point of the `@OrderBy` is to define how the sorting is being done *by the database* (or other datastore).  It translates into a SQL query (or some other request) like as the following.

```
SELECT * FROM `foo` WHERE `id` = ? ORDER BY `val`
```

The data is *not* retrieved and then sorted on the client by the driver or some other entity so there is no way to inject your own comparator.

If you need an alternative sorting strategy then I'm afraid you are going to have to retrieve the items into your code and sort them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

@Gray thanks for the advice, I solved the problem with a different approach and thought I might share it.

We are using JSF with Richfaces 3.1.6GA. Originally I wanted the JPA layer to return the listed already ordered to feed into Richfaces. What we found was that in Richfaces 3.2 and above the functionality of sortBy in baked into the  tag. All you have to specify is a method in which you want to sort by. So my solution was to upgrade to a newer version of Richfaces and add the following method in my entity class.

So in my Person class,

I have a method getNamesWithoutCommas() which as the name implies gets the name without the commas and then use that to sort.

In declaring my column I have something like this:

```
<rich: column sortBy="person.namesWithoutCommas"/>
```